# regForm.reset() clears the form but also disables it?

Tags: angular

.reset() resets my form as expected but after the reset when I try to type again inside input fields then nothing happens the input fields don't accept the inputs.

```
 <form (ngSubmit)="onFormSubmit(regForm)" #regForm="ngForm">
      <div id="tab-2" class="log-tab-content">
        <div class="login-form">
            <div class="confirmation" style="text-align: center;" *ngIf="registered">Registered
                {{regForm.resetForm()}}
            </div>
          <div class="login-left">
            <input type="text" name="first_name" #first_name ngModel required placeholder="First Name *"/>
            <div class="clearfix"></div>
```

Comment: Why are you calling `regForm.resetForm()` within template instead of calling inside `onFormSubmit()` after a successful registration?

Comment: coz this is inside onsubmit in .ts file `this.registered = this.api.registerUser(user) ? true : false;`

Answer (score 0):

Try calling `regForm.restForm()` with in `onFormSubmit()` function in your ts file.

And remove `{{regForm.resetForm()}}` from your template file.